# Ionic2 - Ion-select roto en una página específica

Tags: html, ionic, angularjs-2.0, typescript, ionic2

Estoy haciendo una aplicación Ionic 2, el problema es que cuando se navega a una página específica el componente `ion-select` ni funciona ni se muestra correctamente, pero en otras páginas sí funciona.

Aquí está el fichero TypeScript:

```
// ...

@Component({
  selector: 'page-new-filter',
  templateUrl: 'new-filter.html'
})

export class NewFilterPage {
  form: FormGroup;
  accountId: number;
  localFolders: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: 
NavParams, private platform: Platform, private folders: 
FoldersProvider, private auth: AuthProvider, private formBuilder: 
FormBuilder) {
    this.accountId = navParams.get('id');

    this.form = formBuilder.group({
      type: ["", Validators.required],
      filterText: ["", Validators.required],
      folder: ["", Validators.required]
    });

    this.localFolders = [];

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.folders.getLocalFolders(this.accountId).then((data: any) => {

        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data.item(i)));
          this.localFolders.push(data.item(i));
        }

        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.localFolders));
        console.log(this.accountId);
    });
  });
 }

 // ...

 // ...
}
```

El fichero HTML:

```
...

<ion-list>
<form [formGroup]="form">

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Filtrar por...</ion-label>
    <ion-select formControlName="type" name="type">
      <ion-option value="ssw" selected="true">Asunto comienza por</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="sc">El asunto contiene</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="si">El asunto es</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="fc">El remitente contiene</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

  ...

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Enviar los mensajes a...</ion-label>
    <ion-select formControlName="folder">
      <ion-option value="1" selected="true">Prueba</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="2">Prueba1</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="3">Prueba2</ion-option>

    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

  ...

</form>
```

package.json:

```
/*...*/

"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.8.1",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "3.1.1",
    "@ionic-native/secure-storage": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.1.1",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.28",
    "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-secure-storage": "^2.6.5",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.0.4",
    "ionic-angular": "2.3.0",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.11",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.7.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.1.2",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.1.2",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
},
"cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
],
"cordovaPlatforms": [],
/* ... */
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
        "cordova-plugin-console": {},
        "cordova-plugin-device": {},
        "cordova-plugin-secure-storage": {},
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
        "android"
    ]
}
```

Salida del comando `ionic info`:

```
global packages:

@ionic/cli-utils : 1.1.2
Cordova CLI      :  You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on. 7.0.1 
Ionic CLI        : 3.1.2

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.1.4
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.1.2
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.1.2
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 2.3.0

System:

Node       : v7.10.0
OS         : Linux 4.4
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
```

Capturas de pantalla de la aplicación ejecutándose, estos `ion-select` no funcionan:

[image: Broken ion-select]
[image: Broken ion-select 2]

Además se permite selección múltiple:

[image: Broken radio buttons]

Sin embargo, este `ion-select` de una página diferente funciona:

[image: Working1]
[image: Working2]

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Para futuros visitantes, sólo tuve que actualizar las dependencias para resolver el problema.

Comment: Por favor David, aunque sea tu propia pregunta, la calidad de la respuesta no debe ser menos. Mira [answer] para mejorar la calidad de la misma. Un saludo